# Not getting stored data when navigating to next view

Tags: c#, angularjs, factory

I  am very much troubled by the thing, tat I am not able to store the user info for the next view. Here is my factory:

```
app.factory("currentUser", currentUser);
function currentUser() {
    var profile = {
        userId: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        userEmailId: "",
        userAccessToken: ""
    };

    var setProfile = function (data) {
        profile.userId = "";
        profile.firstName = data.userDetails.frstName;
        profile.lastName = data.userDetails.lastName;
        profile.userEmailId = data.Email;
        profile.userAccessToken = data.userDetails.accessCode;
    }

    var getProfile = function () {
        return profile;
    }

    return {
        setProfile: setProfile,
        getProfile: getProfile
    }
}
```

I set the data using the function:

```
currentUser.setProfile(data);
```

But when in another controller I am trying to get the data I am getting blank object:

```
currentUser.getProfile();
```

Here is my routing

```
  angular.module("angularModule", ["ngAnimate", "ui.router"])
             .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

                 // catch all route
                 // send users to the form page 
                 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                 $stateProvider.state('Register', {
                       url: '/Register',
                       templateUrl: 'Templates/Registration.html',
                       controller: "Registration"
                   })
```

Please help me with the solution I need the solution at earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.factory("myService", function() {
  var profile = {
    userId: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    userEmailId: "",
    userAccessToken: ""
  };
  profile.setProfile = function(userDetails) {
    profile.userId = "";
    profile.firstName = userDetails.frstName;
    profile.lastName = userDetails.lastName;
    profile.userEmailId = userDetails.userEmailId;
    profile.userAccessToken = userDetails.accessCode;
  }
  profile.getProfile = function() {
    return profile;
  }
  return profile;
});
app.controller("ctrl1", ["$scope", "myService", function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.profile = {
    userId: "1233",
    firstName: "JOHN",
    lastName: "DOE",
    userEmailId: "",
    userAccessToken: "314wdw"
  };
  myService.setProfile($scope.profile);
  $scope.valueA = myService.getProfile();
}]);
app.controller("ctrl2", ["$scope", "myService", function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.valueB = myService.getProfile();
}]);
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dGH2U0?p=preview)

Comment: I am still getting blank object. Is my navigation having some issue?? I am getting values in valueA but not after navigating to ctrl2

Comment: No it cannot be, can you create a plunker?

Comment: No i dont know how to create. But the thing is i m confused why it is happening. Is it because I am changing the page like location.href = "/Interests"; It is causing refresh also.. Is this the issue?

Comment: Yes thats the issue! if you change the location controller and factories gets reinitialized. use route instead

Comment: Can you guide how to change the route from the controller.

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal It is completely different topic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126652/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-anirudh-agarwal).

Comment: I got that correct thanks alot and sorry for not able to connect